# Why am I not getting an error when re-declaring a variable?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x;
int main()
{
    int x;
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I not getting an error, even though I am re-declaring the variable `x` with the same name?

Comment: Any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you that different variables of the same name is allowed in different scopes. Perhaps you might take some time to refresh about scopes and variable life-time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and also at the same scope.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: This is yet another of those (rather dubious) behaviours that is perfectly legal in C, that MISRA C seeks to protect you against.

Comment: @Andrew nobody would ever do this on purpose in C (or if they did, they shouldn't be anywhere near critical systems). So it seems like a reasonable rule in thie case

Comment: MM - you would be surprised!

Answer (score 4):

To expand on what Some programmer dude said in the comment,

> A scope is a region of the program and broadly speaking there are three places, where variables can be declared −
>
> - Inside a function or a block which is called local variables,
> - In the definition of function parameters which is called formal
>   parameters.
> - Outside of all functions which is called global variables.

The int x above your main is a global variable which can be used by any function inside your program.

The int x inside your main is a local variable and can only be used logically inside your main.

Check out this link for more info. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: Some words of caution: don't apply to C whatever is written about C++. At this level, the rules are the same, but if you dig deeper, you might find some surprising differences.

Comment: I didn't know about that. My mistake. Should I edit my answer to link a c article about variable scope instead of a c++?

Comment: I think it's fine this way. There is also a lot of bad information on the Internet, so you risk making your link worse.

Comment: The same page haves the C version: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed **although not advised** to define variables with the same names provided that they are not in the same scope. Inside the `main()` function, the `x` in the local scope has more precedence than `x` in the global scope.

But it is confusing and error prone to define variables with the same names. With a compiler like `gcc`, you can activate some options to track them. For example, the "-Wshadow" will warn you that `x` in `main()` shadows the global variable with the same name:

```
$ gcc try.c -Wshadow
try.c: In function ‘main’:
try.c:5:5: warning: declaration of ‘x’ shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]
 int x;
     ^
try.c:2:5: note: shadowed declaration is here
 int x;
     ^
```

Comment: _to define_ --> _to declare_

Comment: @DavidRanieri: both are true no ? The definition tells the compiler the space to reserve for the variable  while the declaration merely tells that a given variable name exists and is defined somewhere.

Comment: Not exactly the same, there are subtle differences, i.e. you can redeclare a variable `int x; int x;` at global scope, but you can not redefine it: `int x = 5; int x = 5;` --> _error: redefinition of ‘x’_. It seems that OP is talking about declarations.